# How to write a function whose both parameters and results are polymorphic in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parameters, polymorphism, typeclass

How can I write a function like `int gog(float i)` and `float gog(int i)` (which is usually called "overloading")? Some simple overloads can be achieved by

```
class PP a where
  gog :: a -> Int

instance PP Bool where
  gog _ = 1

instance PP Char where
  gog _ = 1
```

But the above example only makes the parameter polymorphic.  If we want to make both the parameter and result polymorphic, we have to write something like this:

```
class PP a where
  gog :: Uu b => a -> b

class UU a where
  -- This function can convert between different types of UU.
  fromUuToUu :: UU b => a -> b
```

Without `fromUuToUu`, the polymorphism in the result of `gog` is impossible.  But I can't write `fromUuToUu`, and that is relevant to the theme of this question, which is how to make a function whose parameter and result are both polymorphic.

Comment: It would introduce an ambiguity. If `gog :: Float -> Int` and `gog :: Float -> Float` are defined, what is the type of `gog 5`? Therefore I don't think it is possible. For what purpose do you need it?

Comment: No @Karolis, what is the type of `read "some string"`?, the resulting type can be determine final `read` instance.

Comment: Karolis Juodelė:the gog you refered can be written like this:`class Pgog a where gog :: Float -> a` and `instance Pgog Int where gog _ = 2`and `instance Pgog Float where gog = id`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Poly a b where
  gog :: a -> b

instance Poly Int String where
  gog = show

instance Poly String Int where
  gog = read

instance Poly Int Float where
  gog = fromIntegral

instance Poly Float Float where
  gog = (*) 2
```

`gog` is now "full" polymorphic.

Comment: :It functions like this, really fascinating

    Prelude> :load "Fullpolymorphic2.hs"
    [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Fullpolymorphic2.hs, interpreted )
    Ok, modules loaded: Main.
    *Main> :t gog
    gog :: Poly a b => a -> b
    *Main> (gog (3::Int))::String
    "3"
    *Main> (gog (3::Int))::Float
    3.0
    *Main> (gog ("3"::String))::Int
    3
    *Main> (gog ("3"))::Int
    3
    *Main> (gog ("3"))::String

Comment: from how fromIntegral is defined in GHC.Real like fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
fromIntegral = fromInteger . toInteger. I find that it is a good idea to make a fixed typed medium from polymorphic Parameter and make a polymorphic result from the fixed typed medium

Comment: `gog` will be completely defined when his context will be fully defined. Eg. `take (gog "5") [1..]`.